# SAP HANA Vora: Unable to create vora table

Tags: hana, vora

I am trying to do SAP HANA Vora installation on HDP 2.3 using Ambari 2.2 on a 5 node cluster having 1 management node, 1 master node, 2 worker nodes and 1 jump box node.

After installing all the Vora services, I was trying to validate my installation.

As per the SAP HANA Vora document, I need to create a vora table (table using com.sap.spark.vora) from spark-sql but I am getting Exception. Stack trace below.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SapSQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SapSQLContext

scala> val vc = new SapSQLContext(sc)
16/05/04 06:54:32 INFO SapSQLContext: SapSQLContext [version: 1.2.33] created
vc: org.apache.spark.sql.SapSQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SapSQLContext@69e4e90b

scala> val testsql = """
     | CREATE TABLE table001 (a1 double, a2 int, a3 string)
     | USING com.sap.spark.vora
     | OPTIONS (tablename "table001", paths "/user/vora/test.csv")"""
testsql: String =
"
CREATE TABLE table001 (a1 double, a2 int, a3 string)
USING com.sap.spark.vora
OPTIONS (tablename "table001", paths "/user/vora/test.csv")"

scala> vc.sql(testsql)
OperationException{statusCode=500, statusMessage='Internal Server Error', statusContent='No cluster leader'}
        at com.ecwid.consul.v1.health.HealthConsulClient.getHealthServices(HealthConsulClient.java:96)
        at com.ecwid.consul.v1.health.HealthConsulClient.getHealthServices(HealthConsulClient.java:80)
        at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient.getHealthServices(ConsulClient.java:324)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.discovery.ConsulDiscoveryClient$ConsulDiscoveryClient.lookupService(ConsulDiscoveryClient.scala:45)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.config.VoraConfiguration$.apply(VoraConfiguration.scala:37)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.DefaultSource.buildConfiguration(DefaultSource.scala:403)
        at com.sap.spark.vora.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.resolveDataSource(CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.run(CreateTableUsingTemporaryAwareCommand.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:725)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
        at <init>(<console>:46)
        at .<init>(<console>:50)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:685)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Kindly help me with this issue...

Answer (score 0):

The error message `No cluster leader` indicates that the Vora Discovery Service is not running correctly. You need min 3 Discovery Servers on 3 different nodes and Discover Clients on all other nodes (never run Client and Server on the same node; they are mutually exclusive as they use the same port 8500). The Discovery Servers will elect a leader amongst themselves - according to the message this step did not happen. Likely cause is that < 3 servers are running correctly.

To solve the issue, run at least 3 Discovery Servers. Given that you have 1 master and 2 workers you probably want to run a Discovery server on each of the 3 nodes (no Discovery Clients on nodes that run Discovery Servers). The jump box should get a Discovery Clinet. For troubleshooting please see the [Vora Installation and Administration Guide](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/hana_vora/SAP_HANA_Vora_Installation_Admin_Guide_en.pdf) and the [Troubleshooting Blog](http://scn.sap.com/blogs/vora/2015/12/09/sap-hana-vora--troubleshooting) (section 'How to?' -> How to check the status of the Vora discovery service?)

Comment: Hi Frank,

Thanks for your quick response on this.

However, I have checked that I have installed Vora Discovery service on all the nodes( on 3 nodes in server mode and on remaining 2 in client mode). 
None of the nodes are having the service installed in both server and client mode. 
Also, all the nodes and services are up and running fine as well.

The only issue I can see is that among the 3 server nodes, none of the nodes became a leader (leader election didn't happen or might be nodes are trying to prevent the split-brain scenario as per Consul documentation).

Comment: I even tried manually bootstrapping the cluster but didn't helped.

Comment: It seems the 3 discovery servers are not installed correctly. Could you please open a ticket with SAP in component HAN-VO.